# How to access to my personal computer from work using VNC

Tags: http, https, raspberry-pi, portforwarding, vnc

I want to access to all kind of webpages without restriction from work, so I thought I could set up a vnc server on my raspberry pi, forward 80 port to 5900 port (for example) on my router and try to access to my raspi from work using a client like RealVNC. Now the question would be, Is this going to work? If not, what would be the correct solution?

Comment: Independent of the actual answer, doing so is very likely a breach of your company's security policy. Depending on how seriously your employer takes security, it could very well be a firing offense.

Answer (score 0):

**Start with this video overview:** [Raspberry Pi - How to put your Pi Online](http://youtu.be/G0Lg4O-eeRQ)

1. **Use the TightVNC Server** as it is widely supported and compatible with the Raspberry Pi. Here's a tutorial on how to setup a Tight VNC server on the Raspberry Pi: [Raspberry Pi - Installing VNC server](http://youtu.be/c5QCoh8S0N4)
2. **Setup Dynamic DNS** on your Raspberry Pi. This will give you one address to point your VNC viewer at that will stay the same. With out it your address may change every now and then at the ISP's discretion.
3. **Setup TightVNC Viewer** on your work computer and point it to your new dynamic address and your TightVNC servers port. Then connect.